# TV animated series where the villain would casually change his eyes' color from blue to red

Tags: story-identification, tv, animated-series

I'm looking for a series or a character (Most probably a villain) who would casually change his eyes' color; by casually, I mean that he had blue eyes, but then he would close them and when reopening them they would turn red. I have the impression that it was *Digimon*, but I'm unable to find any character fitting that description.

Physically, I have vague memories of him looking alike the villain of *The Secret Saturdays* named V.V. Argost or a *Yu-Gi-Oh* card named "Vampire Baby". I kinda remember a semi bald haircut, one resembling Miguel Hidalgo's one, but ignore this part since it is very likely that I remember it wrongly.

I know the description is vague, but that's all I can remember. I'm unaware if it was a cartoon, an anime or if it was from the '90s or early 2000s.

Comment: Maybe Death Note?

Comment: Maybe worth a look at https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GlowingEyesOfDoom or https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RedEyesTakeWarning or https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GlowingEyes

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a long shot, since all it matches is the character having blue eyes, closing them and opening them with red eyes to unleash his evil side, but the character Gemini Saga from [*Saint Seiya*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Seiya#Anime) is a possible match.

[image: Close-up of Gemini Saga's face with blue eyes]

[image: Close-up of Gemini Saga's face with his eyes closed]

[image: Close-up of Gemini Saga's face with his eyes now red]

Note: How the eyes were depicted as red varied over the course of the anime and the following OVA, but it was still blink-and-change.

[image: Gemini Saga with eyes having red sclera, not pupils]